# Dealloc method in class category

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've been looking at some third-party code that adds a class category to UITableView; the interface adds three methods, but the implementation also includes code for the -dealloc method (among other helper methods).

I'm not super familiar with class categories - aside from this seeming like a bad thing to do, does this override the -dealloc method for all instances of UITableView - even if the category is not imported by a particular class (say a ViewController) that instantiates a UITableView?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Toss that code as it is clearly garbage (post a link to it, if you can).

Assuming it really is a category on `UITableView`, that `dealloc` will effectively replace -- override, but without inheritance -- the class's normal `dealloc`, thereby guaranteeing misbehavior.   Not only will it destroy the functionality of all instances of UITableView, it'll mess up all subclasses, too.

Even if it isn't a category on `UITableView`, but some attempt to organize code, then the `dealloc` is in the wrong place.  It should **always** be on the class's primary `@implementation`.  Just like a class cluster will implement all primitive methods on the main implementation -- `dealloc` is very much a primitive method (where a "primitive" method is a method that is core to a class's functionality and is only implemented in terms of other primitive methods).

Comment: @bbum - that's what seemed to be happening when I tested it (and what another one of your answers on another question seemed to say) - but I just wasn't sure what was supposed to happen since it wasn't imported in that particular class (it was elsewhere).  The code in question is https://github.com/zhigang1992/ZGParallelView

Comment: Wow.  Thanks for the link.  Bug filed.  Quite frightening to see how popular those repositories are given that kind of a bug!